# Kafka Connect Debezium error while filtering

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

For config:

curl -X POST "${KAFKA_CONNECT_HOST}/connectors" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ 
"name": "DebeziumSMS", 
"config": { 
"connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector", 
"tasks.max": 1, 
"database.hostname": "bill-srv02.corp.oblakowifi.ru", 
"database.port": 1433, 
"database.user": "sa", 
"database.password": "******", 
"database.dbname": "sms", 
"database.server.name": "server-test", 
"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "192.168.26.142:9092", 
"database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.sms", 
"errors.log.enable": "true", 
"database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true", 
"time.precision.mode": "connect", 
"transforms": "filter", 
"transforms.filter.type": "io.debezium.transforms.Filter", 
"transforms.filter.language": "jsr223.groovy", 
"transforms.filter.condition": "value.op == ''c''" 
} 
}'

this error:

```
[2021-10-19 12:50:46,234] ERROR Error encountered in task DebeziumSMS-0. Executing stage 'TRANSFORMATION' with class 'io.debezium.transforms.Filter'. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter:66)
io.debezium.DebeziumException: Error while evaluating expression 'value.op == 'c'' for record 'SourceRecord{sourcePartition={server=server-test}, sourceOffset={transaction_id=null, event_serial_no=1, commit_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0003, change_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0002}} ConnectRecord{topic='server-test', kafkaPartition=0, key=Struct{databaseName=sms}, keySchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SchemaChangeKey:STRUCT}, value=Struct{source=Struct{version=1.5.0.Final,connector=sqlserver,name=server-test,ts_ms=1634637045699,db=,schema=,table=,change_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0002,commit_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0003},databaseName=sms,schemaName=dbo,ddl=N/A,tableChanges=[Struct{type=ALTER,id="sms"."dbo"."sms",table=Struct{primaryKeyColumnNames=[id],columns=[Struct{name=id,jdbcType=1,typeName=uniqueidentifier,typeExpression=uniqueidentifier,length=36,position=1,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=creator_login,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=64,position=2,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=system_ip_address,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=3,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=system_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=4,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=system_sub_id,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=5,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=type_id,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=6,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=date_create,jdbcType=93,typeName=datetime,typeExpression=datetime,length=23,scale=3,position=7,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=date_send,jdbcType=93,typeName=datetime,typeExpression=datetime,length=23,scale=3,position=8,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=date_state,jdbcType=93,typeName=datetime,typeExpression=datetime,length=23,scale=3,position=9,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=time_to_live,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=10,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=state_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=11,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=phone,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=32,position=12,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=target_id,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=13,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=provider_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=14,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=message,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=2147483647,position=15,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=linked_file,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=4000,position=16,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=error_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=17,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=error_msg,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=4000,position=18,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}]}}]}, valueSchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SchemaChangeValue:STRUCT}, timestamp=null, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)}'
        at io.debezium.transforms.scripting.Jsr223Engine.eval(Jsr223Engine.java:116)
        at io.debezium.transforms.Filter.doApply(Filter.java:33)
        at io.debezium.transforms.ScriptingTransformation.apply(ScriptingTransformation.java:189)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:323)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:248)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: op is not a valid field name
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
        at io.debezium.transforms.scripting.Jsr223Engine.eval(Jsr223Engine.java:107)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: op is not a valid field name
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.lookupField(Struct.java:254)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.get(Struct.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:62)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:329)
        at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317)
        ... 19 more
[2021-10-19 12:50:46,237] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=DebeziumSMS-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:487)
[2021-10-19 12:50:46,237] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=DebeziumSMS-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:184)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:323)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:248)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.debezium.DebeziumException: Error while evaluating expression 'value.op == 'c'' for record 'SourceRecord{sourcePartition={server=server-test}, sourceOffset={transaction_id=null, event_serial_no=1, commit_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0003, change_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0002}} ConnectRecord{topic='server-test', kafkaPartition=0, key=Struct{databaseName=sms}, keySchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SchemaChangeKey:STRUCT}, value=Struct{source=Struct{version=1.5.0.Final,connector=sqlserver,name=server-test,ts_ms=1634637045699,db=,schema=,table=,change_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0002,commit_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0003},databaseName=sms,schemaName=dbo,ddl=N/A,tableChanges=[Struct{type=ALTER,id="sms"."dbo"."sms",table=Struct{primaryKeyColumnNames=[id],columns=[Struct{name=id,jdbcType=1,typeName=uniqueidentifier,typeExpression=uniqueidentifier,length=36,position=1,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=creator_login,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=64,position=2,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=system_ip_address,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=3,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=system_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=4,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=system_sub_id,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=5,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=type_id,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=6,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=date_create,jdbcType=93,typeName=datetime,typeExpression=datetime,length=23,scale=3,position=7,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=date_send,jdbcType=93,typeName=datetime,typeExpression=datetime,length=23,scale=3,position=8,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=date_state,jdbcType=93,typeName=datetime,typeExpression=datetime,length=23,scale=3,position=9,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=time_to_live,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=10,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=state_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=11,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=phone,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=32,position=12,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=target_id,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=13,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=provider_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=14,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=message,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=2147483647,position=15,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=linked_file,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=4000,position=16,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=error_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=17,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=error_msg,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=4000,position=18,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}]}}]}, valueSchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SchemaChangeValue:STRUCT}, timestamp=null, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)}'
        at io.debezium.transforms.scripting.Jsr223Engine.eval(Jsr223Engine.java:116)
        at io.debezium.transforms.Filter.doApply(Filter.java:33)
        at io.debezium.transforms.ScriptingTransformation.apply(ScriptingTransformation.java:189)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: op is not a valid field name
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
        at io.debezium.transforms.scripting.Jsr223Engine.eval(Jsr223Engine.java:107)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: op is not a valid field name
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.lookupField(Struct.java:254)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.get(Struct.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:62)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:329)
        at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317)
        ... 19 more
[2021-10-19 12:50:46,237] INFO Stopping down connector (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:238)
```

After recreating Debezium Connector by DELETE and next POST, Debezium works fine a few days. But then error repeats, and connector stopps with this error.
And after reboot Kafka Connect (distributed) service this error again.

Trace for connector error by REST :

```
"trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:323)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:248)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: io.debezium.DebeziumException: Error while evaluating expression 'value && value.op == 'c'' for record 'SourceRecord{sourcePartition={server=server-test}, sourceOffset={transaction_id=null, event_serial_no=1, commit_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0003, change_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0002}} ConnectRecord{topic='server-test', kafkaPartition=0, key=Struct{databaseName=sms}, keySchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SchemaChangeKey:STRUCT}, value=Struct{source=Struct{version=1.5.0.Final,connector=sqlserver,name=server-test,ts_ms=1634805618423,db=,schema=,table=,change_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0002,commit_lsn=00000064:0000420c:0003},databaseName=sms,schemaName=dbo,ddl=N/A,tableChanges=[Struct{type=ALTER,id=\"sms\".\"dbo\".\"sms\",table=Struct{primaryKeyColumnNames=[id],columns=[Struct{name=id,jdbcType=1,typeName=uniqueidentifier,typeExpression=uniqueidentifier,length=36,position=1,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=creator_login,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=64,position=2,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=system_ip_address,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=3,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=system_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=4,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=system_sub_id,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=5,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=type_id,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=6,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=date_create,jdbcType=93,typeName=datetime,typeExpression=datetime,length=23,scale=3,position=7,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=date_send,jdbcType=93,typeName=datetime,typeExpression=datetime,length=23,scale=3,position=8,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=date_state,jdbcType=93,typeName=datetime,typeExpression=datetime,length=23,scale=3,position=9,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=time_to_live,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=10,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=state_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=11,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=phone,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=32,position=12,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=target_id,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=128,position=13,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=provider_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=14,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=message,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=2147483647,position=15,optional=false,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=linked_file,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=4000,position=16,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=error_id,jdbcType=4,typeName=int,typeExpression=int,length=10,scale=0,position=17,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}, Struct{name=error_msg,jdbcType=12,typeName=varchar,typeExpression=varchar,length=4000,position=18,optional=true,autoIncremented=false,generated=false}]}}]}, valueSchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SchemaChangeValue:STRUCT}, timestamp=null, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)}'\n\tat io.debezium.transforms.scripting.Jsr223Engine.eval(Jsr223Engine.java:116)\n\tat io.debezium.transforms.Filter.doApply(Filter.java:33)\n\tat io.debezium.transforms.ScriptingTransformation.apply(ScriptingTransformation.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)\n\t... 11 more\nCaused by: javax.script.ScriptException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: op is not a valid field name\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71)\n\tat javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)\n\tat io.debezium.transforms.scripting.Jsr223Engine.eval(Jsr223Engine.java:107)\n\t... 16 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: op is not a valid field name\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.lookupField(Struct.java:254)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.get(Struct.java:74)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)\n\tat groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:62)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:329)\n\tat Script3.run(Script3.groovy:1)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317)\n\t... 19 more\n"}
```

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: op is not a valid field name
> Why?

What can be wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: According to the error, not every event has an op field

Comment: According https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/transformations/filtering.html
'value' is "A value of the message"
'value.c' is a field, which is created by Debezium as current CDC  operation in MSSQL.
And transforms.filter.condition from example https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/transformations/filtering.html#example-basic-filter-configuration-example does not check (!value && value.op)